# Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Sum

Tags: sql-server-2008

Data for every month is there till December. I want to get a new column as "sum" , which will sum till the previous month. Means, now it is august. So, the sum should be placed till july as shown in first entry in "Sum" column below.

```
Jan| Feb| Mar| Apr| May| Jun |Jul |Aug |Sum     
21 | 28 | 26 | 31 | 54 | 67  |38  |29  |265             
11 | 44 | 66 | 7  | 88 | 54  |90  |74  |                
13 | 45 | 26 | 38 | 36 | 39  |67  |49  |            
76 | 35 | 67 | 23 | 76 | 54  |35  |59  |
```

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic query?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
What did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, dynamic query is needed. The query should work for next year also. It should show the average for entire 12 months of this year on January of next year. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Since months are closed set, I prefer this simple solution:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=1 THEN 0 ELSE Jan END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=2 THEN 0 ELSE Feb END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=3 THEN 0 ELSE Mar END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=4 THEN 0 ELSE Apr END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=5 THEN 0 ELSE May END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=6 THEN 0 ELSE Jun END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=7 THEN 0 ELSE Jul END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=8 THEN 0 ELSE Aug END +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date)<=9 THEN 0 ELSE Sep END Sum
    --Append 3 more months to DECEMBER
FROM Months
```

Comment: But the query should work for next year also. It should show the average for entire 12 months of this year on January of next year. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr, and so on...
  ,COALESCE(Jan,0) + COALESCE(Feb,0) + COALESCE(Mar,0) + COALESCE(Apr,0)..(till Dec) AS "Sum"
FROM MyTable
```

IF a row entrie is NULL the SUM will be NULL, therefor is the COALESCE-Function which will turn a NULL into ZERO

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DATE date
SET @date = GETDATE()
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @DATE), 3)
```